# When would I use K analysis over NNA?

Tags: spatial-statistics, nearest-neighbor

I'm working with the dataset Redwood (62 redwood trees in a 23^2m square).

I intend to test whether these are random or not.

In what cases would I prefer Nearest Neighbor Analysis and in what cases K Analysis?